How do I find an uncovered zero in Hungarian algorithm?
I'm trying to implement the Hungarian algorithm for the assignment problem. In the Munkres version it says "Step 1: Choose a non-covered zero and prime it" (see p33 https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/data/emd/munkres.pdf). The instruction in the wiki is similar (see Step 4 at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm#Matrix_interpretation).
How do I actually implement it? Checking $n^2$ entries and searching for 0 seems slow. And I don't see a clear path to maintaining a list of currently uncovered zeroes.
UPD: maybe I can have a list of columns to check and once I uncover the column I add it to the end of the list. In this way, I will only check each entry once during this step I think. So $n^2$ checks for the whole step instead of $n^2$ checks for each zero.

You can map each row index and each column index to three sets of cells: covered zeros; primed zeros; and zeros that are neither covered nor primed. When a zero changes status, you remove it from the relevant previous sets in the row and column maps and add it to the relevant new sets. Looking for a non-starred zero in a row just means looking up the proper sets in the row maps for that row and seeing if they are empty. Checking whether a starred / primed / anointed zero is in the same row/column as a given zero is again just a matter of looking up the row or column index in the corresponding maps and seeing if the associated sets are empty.
